# Will using REST API from my site hosted on wordpress.com result in duplicate content?

Tags: wordpress, duplicate-content, api, restful

I have a blog on wordpress.com to store content.  I want to access that content using the REST API for a non-wordpress website.

My question is, will this result in duplicate content (on wordpress.com and my website) in the eyes of search engines?  If so, how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be duplicate content unless everything is identical on a page,  which includes your template/design output ( effectively a clone of the site ).  It could however be seen as syndicated content,  of which the content which gets indexed first will be the authority. ( There are exceptions to that rule ).

If you are not bothered about the Wordpress.com site from being indexed, you could simply hide it from search engines allowing your rest API syndication to be the primary content publisher.

You can do that in Wordpress.com by going to the

WP-admin - Settings - Reading : **Discourage search engines from indexing this site**